# HERE Geocode search API is not returning the city for some german postal codes

Tags: here-api

We are using the HERE API for a looking up the city assigned to a postal code. So if we take the postal code `99947` for example, the API returns the following Address without a city. The expected city is `Bad Langensalza`

```
GET https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=99947&apiKey=apiKey&limit=5&in=countryCode:DEU
```

```
"address": {
                "label": "99947, Thüringen, Deutschland",
                "countryCode": "DEU",
                "countryName": "Deutschland",
                "stateCode": "TH",
                "state": "Thüringen",
                "countyCode": "UH",
                "county": "Unstrut-Hainich-Kreis",
                "postalCode": "99947"
            },
```

*EDIT: Copy and paste error in response, added the correct one now*

If you lookup the city `Bad Langensalza` you do get the postal code, so you can see that it should be working.

```
GET https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=Bad%20Langensalza&apiKey=apiKey&limit=5&in=countryCode:DEU
```

```
    "address": {
                "label": "Bad Langensalza, Thüringen, Deutschland",
                "countryCode": "DEU",
                "countryName": "Deutschland",
                "stateCode": "TH",
                "state": "Thüringen",
                "countyCode": "UH",
                "county": "Unstrut-Hainich-Kreis",
                "city": "Bad Langensalza",
                "postalCode": "99947"
            },
```

What is the issue that we would not get the city in the first query, but we do get it in the second query?

Comment: Hi, I cannot reproduce the first result of geocode search query for 99947. Could you please confirm it again? My result city is "title": "99947, Thüringen, Deutschland"

Comment: Hey, sorry yes that was a copy and paste issue on my side. I updated the response in the question now. The result you are getting is the correct one.

Comment: Hello, We are able to replicate the issue. We will raise it to over product team and will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

If we can not uniquely identify one city for a postal code then city is not returned.The next hierarchy which is State is returned. This is always like this in HLS and there are no plans to fix this behaviour in HLS.